# Adding data definitions to structs in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

```
(define-struct animal (name species age breakfast-hour dinner-hour))  
(define-struct attendant (name a1 a2 a3))
(define attendant1 (make-attendant "Dave" 'gorillas 'bats 'mandrills ))
(define attendant2 (make-attendant "John" 'crocodiles 'ocelots 'capybara ))                                  
(define attendant3 (make-attendant "Joe" 'pottos 'tapirs 'vultures ))
```

How would I add data definitions to these? All this currently gives me is  "(E.g. ;; An animal is...)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you define the structures:

```
(define-struct animal (name species age breakfast-hour dinner-hour))
(define-struct attendant (name a1 a2 a3))
```

Then, the animals (because you need to create these before assigning them to attendants):

```
(define gorilla (make-animal "Koko" "Gorilla" 4 8 10))
(define bat (make-animal "Bruce" "Bat" 1 23 5))
(define mandrill (make-animal "Manny" "Mandrill" 5 8 10))
(define crocodile (make-animal "Swampy" "Crocodile" 1 10 18))
(define ocelot (make-animal "Ozzy" "Ocelot" 7 7 17))
(define capybara (make-animal "Capy" "Capybara" 4 6 18))
(define potto (make-animal "Spot" "Potto" 2 2 6))
(define tapir (make-animal "Stripey" "Tapir" 3 10 17))
(define vulture (make-animal "Beaky" "Vulture" 10 9 19))
```

And finally, you create the attendants, giving each guy or gal their corresponding animals:

```
(define attendant1 (make-attendant "Dave" gorilla bat mandrill))
(define attendant2 (make-attendant "John" crocodile ocelot capybara))
(define attendant3 (make-attendant "Joe" potto tapir vulture))
```

Notice that for creating the attendants, we must reference one of the previously defined animals.